# Regex to match strings starting and ending with %%

Tags: php, regex

I have a text that has multiple occurrences of variables in this format:

```
Example text will %%include%% these %%parameters%%
```

I'm trying to use this:

`preg_match('/%%[\s\S]*?%%/i',$output, $matches);`

But for some reason I'm getting only the first match, any ideas?

Comment: You don't need `[\s\S]` in PHP (as opposed to JavaScript). A simple `.` is enough when you set the `/s` option. Also, you don't need the `/i` option because there are no cased characters in your regex anyway: `'/%%.*?%%/s'` will do (together with `preg_match_all()`).

Comment: @EmilVikström: Well, it's not really an answer to his question (which was about why he only got one match). But perhaps Pierpaolo could incorporate it into his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) because you need multiple matches.

Comment: easy fix, thanks for that. I'll accept your answer once I can